# Remote testing environment in Visual studio 2022 not starting

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-2022

I have this dockerfile:

```
# test environment for the
# "orcasql-breadth-Onebranch-buddy-PGMigrationSidecarTests" pipeline. Any
# changes made to this file should also be reflected in the '.pipelines' folder
# at the root of the 'orcasql-breadth' repository.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal

ARG PORT=5678

# Install PostgreSQL 12
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER postgres

# Initialize PostgreSQL
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
    psql -c "select 1" && \
    psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'placeholder';" && \
    psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = logical;" && \
    psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET max_wal_senders = 20;" && \
    psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET max_replication_slots = 20;" && \
    sed -i -e 's/port = .*/port = '$PORT'/g' /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql restart && \
    export PGPASSWORD=placeholder && \
    psql -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres -p $PORT -c "select 1" && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql stop

# Switch back to the root user
USER root

CMD /etc/init.d/postgresql start && bash
```

I am trying to run this above dockerfile as a remote environment for tests execution in Visual studio 2022. When I select this docker environment from the dropdown in the test explorer, the corresponding tests disappear.
Docker is not getting started with the below error;

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint awesome_beaver (41259dd825e03b5254087a924f241ebc6b409b1e7fd32256869f0b830cedb359): listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:50067: bind: address already in use

Error: failed to start containers: bd59175c791f
```

I tried restarting the docker desktop app, WSL , and visual studio but nothing helped. How to get around this error?